# Object.keys().forEach() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was creating a menu with icons, reacting on user's mouse with javascript, like ":hover" pseudo element in CSS.
Firstly I tried to use this code:

```
var hmpg_link = document.getElementById("homepage_link"),
hmpg_pic = document.getElementById("homepage_pic");

hmpg_link.onmouseenter = function () {
    hmpg_pic.src = "images/menu/active/homepage.png";
};   

hmpg_link.onmouseenter = function () {
    hmpg_pic.src = "images/menu/active/homepage.png";
};
```

And it worked! But because I have a lot of menu points, I tried to automize this process and wrote this code.

```
var hmpg = {"link": document.getElementById("homepage_link"),
    "img": document.getElementById("homepage_pic")},
names = {hmpg: "homepage"},
path = "images/menu/";

Object.keys(names).forEach(function (item) {
    item["link"].onmouseenter = function () {
        item["img"].src = path + "active/" + names[item] + ".png";
    };

    item["link"].onmouseleave = function () {
        item["img"].src = path + "normal/" + names[item] + ".png";
    };
});
```

And this code doesn't work. There aren't any error in browser console, images in menu just don't change.

Comment: `:hover` is a pseudo-class, not a pseudo-element.

Comment: Could you please explain what "doesn't work" means. What are the symptoms? What are you expecting? are there any errors in the console.

Comment: Where is the closing of object `hmpg`?

Comment: From your explanation you seem to have multiple elements with the same `id`. Each element should have its own `id`, if you want to share a common attribute selector you can use `class` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are selecting the object dynamically based on your value. Looping thought `Object.keys(names)` will give you `hmpg` in the `item` value of `forEach()` and using that `item` you are trying to access the property `link` and `img` i.e, `item['link']` and `item['img']` which is incorrect and raise you error.

However, to achieve that you can nest your `hmpg` object inside another object, say, `mapObj` then everything will be same except the way you will access the `link` and `img` value. This time it will be `mapObj[item]['link']` and `mapObj[item]['img']`. This way it will work for you.

```js
var mapObj = {
  hmpg: {
    "link": 'someLink',
    "img": 'someImg'
  }
};
var names = {
    hmpg: "homepage"
}
var path = "images/menu/";

Object.keys(names).forEach(function(item) {
  console.log(mapObj[item]['link']);
  console.log(mapObj[item]['img']);
});
```